# Read environment properties from Elastic Beanstalk in .ebextensions

Tags: .net, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-server, ebextensions

I've set some properties with their values in Elastic Beanstalk on Amazon. An example is:
[image]

I have a .NET application which I will deploy on an EC2 Windows server with IIS. The .NET project contains an `.ebextensions` folder in which we include `.config` files to do further configurations.

Now is my question. Am I able to read the value of a property (so read "root" from property DB.Username" inside a `.config` file in the `.ebextensions` folder?

I tried something like this but it seems that a property of Elastic Beanstalk isn't a real Windows environment variable

```
commands:
  010-01-test:
    command: echo %DB.Username%
```

I know those variables are also used in `web.config` in my project. But it seems an ugly solution to me to get the values out of this file?

Comment: In AWS the abbreviation EBS stands for Elastic Block Store, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @MarkB You're right. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. I found the solution here https://blog.corpinfo.com/how-to-call-and-export-variables-in-elastic-beanstalk

For unix you can simply write

```
commands:
  010-01-test:
    command: echo $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k DB.Username)
```

or even `$(get-config environment -k DB.Username):`

I don't know how to expose this inline in windows, but there are should be a way.

Alternative you can try more verbose solution

```
commands:
  010-01-test:
    command: echo %DBUsername%
    env:
      DBUsername: 
        "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
          Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
          OptionName: DB.Username
```

Comment: Does the above need to be run directly on the EC2 instance of the beanstalk? Can I run it in a way similar to "describe-environments" ?

Comment: You may try describe-configuration-settings if CLI is what you need

Comment: That actually worked! For anyone else looking, you may need to `yum install jq` if you are trying to fetch a particular value. Example:  `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-configuration-settings --application-name appname --environment-name envname | jq '.ConfigurationSettings[].OptionSettings'| jq '.[] | select(.OptionName=="IMPORTANT_CONFIG_VALUE")'|jq '.Value'`